# How to set the calendar in android for particular hour

Tags: java, android

I dont want to add the year or month.Just the hour , minutes and seconds for each day.
How to use it the Calendar object to do it ?
This is my code

```
// get a Calendar object with current time
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
// add 5 minutes to the calendar object

cal.add(Calendar.HOUR, 4);
cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 40);




Intent i = new Intent(this, Receiver.class);
i.putExtra("alarm_message", "O'Doyle Rules!");
// In reality, you would want to have a static variable for the request code instead of 192837
PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 192837, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

// Get the AlarmManager service
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), sender);
```

Answer (score 63, accepted):

try using

```
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 4);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 40);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
```

Answer (score 14):

try this too

```
cal.set(2013,2,7,15,42,30);
```

**Note:** Months value is `MonthNumber-1` (`Jan is 0`, `Feb is 1` and so on).