# Issue getting the days difference between future date and current date in java

Tags: java, javascript

I need to pick a future date from calendar, suppose the date I am selecting is 04/30/2013. Now what I want is to send the date to server. At server end I need to calculate the number of days between the future date and current date and send it to database.

The problem is that when I do the calculation locally (because my server and browser are in same timezone) it works fine, but when the server is in a different timezone than the browser the difference in days does not come as expected. Someone please help me how to solve the timezone issues.

Comment: Why don't you substract the dates on the client?

Comment: How do you send the date to the server? What format, I mean?

Comment: @user2266098 That would be a violation of the MVC paradigm.

Comment: Your question is not entirely clear to me: you are using javascript on the client side and java on your server ?

Comment: Well, you could simply pass the utc time to the server which generates the dates and calc the days between.

Answer (score 0):

### To Offset for time differences

You should use a format to send the data that includes the timezone within it. 
You could:

1. Use UNIX time which does not use timezones (milliseconds since epoch) with GMT 00, and also use this on java side

see:
[Get current date/time in seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3830244/get-current-date-time-in-seconds)

2. Use ISO-8601 which is a standard and can include the timezone as well of the browser, and then parse this server side:

see:

- [How do I output an ISO 8601 formatted string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573521/how-do-i-output-an-iso-8601-formatted-string-in-javascript) and
- [Converting ISO 8601-compliant String to java.util.Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201925/converting-iso8601-compliant-string-to-java-util-date)

### To Calculate the Difference (using MS and Calendar Object)

You need to use the calendar object.
You create a calendar object and set with a future date: e.g. [How to set Java.util.calendar to a specific time period in the future](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12649288/how-to-set-java-util-calendar-to-a-specific-time-period-in-the-future)
Then you can perform a calculation by subtracting the current date (as long) with the long returned by the calendar, and dividing by (1000*60*60*24).

Some code I used in my own application to find entries greater than a specific datetime (midnight):

```
long currentTimeStamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
Calendar cal;
cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(new Date(currentTimeStamp));

//GET MS OF MIDNIGHT FROM BEGINNING OF THE DAY
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0); cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0); cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0); cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND,0);
long midnight = cal.getTimeInMillis();
if(currentTimeStamp - midnight > (30*24*60*60*1000))break;
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert both dates in one common timezone e.g. GMT and then calculate the difference.